# What's the tools for testing of Azure configuration created from ARM template?

Tags: testing, azure-resource-manager

Of course, each resource should be tested in individual way. But maybe some tools exist which provide some framework and help to automate and to connect typical steps?
I mean:

- Template validation - for example with ARM template test toolkit
- Logs analysis after deployment (for errors, for example)
- Testing typical Azure resources by their types
- etc

Comment: So what s the question ?  the title ? I dont think there is any obvious answer, everything depends on what you re trying to achieve^^

Comment: Something like that
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/considerations/azure-test-driven-development
but more detail and technical.

Answer (score 0):

We can check for template validation if we develop our [ARM template in VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msazurermtools.azurerm-vscode-tools), as it will show us the architecture of our template design.

To check for errors, when you select Powershell as interpreter and execute your ARM template from .ps script. It will give us all the error and status about the execution.

So according to this, we can test by implementing in Azure portal and need to check the deployed infrastructure and executed output. Ideally, we can achieve these from VS Code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Do I really need VS Code? Can I do all these things in VS Community Edition?

Comment: Yes, you can make it done